# Adding Dynamic View is TableLayout

Tags: android, performance, tablelayout

I have a UI like below attached screen.

[image: TableLayout with Dummy Data]

So I opted `TableLayout`. 
Now data is coming from API and number of records is more than 300.

`TableLayout` is inside `ScrollView`. I have to add rows in `TableLayout` dynamically because data is coming from Webservices.

Now since I add more than 300 views dynamically as a row of `TableLayout` screen responds slow. Its taking time to add and draw views.

Below is my logic to add dynamic view

```
TableLayout table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
for(int count=0;count<data.size();count++)
{
   // Here I create dynamic TableRow and set Data inside Row
   table.addView(row);
}
```

The reason I chose `TableLayout` is to keep data in a row and column format only.

`LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout` inside `ListView` is not keeping the alignment proper.

Can anyone suggest me more optimized solution ?

Below is xml file where I have used LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRank"
        style="@style/txt_normal_dark_gray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDriverName"
        style="@style/txt_normal_dark_gray"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPts"
        style="@style/txt_normal_dark_gray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWins"
        style="@style/txt_normal_dark_gray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now guess sometime txtDriverName is having long string or txtWins is an empty string, does the next list row item will have same alignment ? Also I tried using weight_sum and gave weight to all TextViews.

Comment: Just curious - LinearLayout/RelativeLayout was responding fast then TableLayout ?

Comment: A ListView is what you want. If you setup the row layout correctly, i.e. with `layout_width=0dp` and the appropriate `layout_weight` for the TextViews inside a LinearLayout, it should work nicely.

Comment: I agree with @Mike. You should use a ListView and for each row use LinearLayout with layout_weight.

Comment: @MikeM.layout_weight will change for next row, say if length of Name Stringis more it will adjust points and wins in different manner. Already tried that. But still if you have some code snippet which does the same using ListView, please share me or guide me to achieve same

Comment: @Ved Prakash , nope I tried those for weight and alignment purpose.

Comment: `layout_weight` should not change from row to row. Post the layout you tried with the ListView.

Comment: So as I thought, the layouts are not responsible for slow or fast response. It is the query, calculations, logic or data usage that makes response slow or fast. Try to work on these.

Comment: @MikeM.Edited the question, which has xml file which I have tried for ListView row item. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Ok, the problem is that _every_ `TextView` needs to have its `layout_width` set to 0, and a `layout_weight` defined. The reason the rows aren't aligning is because some of the TextViews are set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: So Mike, you are suggesting that I should set width of every textview 0dip and give weight to them and use weight sum. Right ?

Comment: You don't need to define a `weightSum`. For example, to get a layout similar to what your image shows, set the `layout_weight` of the first `TextView` to 1, the second to 6, the third to 2, and the fourth to 1. You may also need to set `android:singleLine="true"` for each one, as well.

Comment: Let me try. Thanks Mike

Comment: @MikeM. It works. Conclusion, Always keep width or height 0dip when using layout_weight . Thanks again Mike.